# The Newtonian limit of torsion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, differential-geometry

[Torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor) is a common modification to general relativity. It is loosely described as gyroscopes twisting along geodesics.

A gyroscope is basically a mass-spring system. The masses making up the spinning disk try to follow geodesics but are prevented from flying away by the springs which maintain proper distance.

At low speeds, in otherwise flat spacetime, how would torsion change the rotation axis of a moving gyroscope? Suppose we add a torsion force, given in index notation as: $F_{t,i}=T_{ijk}F_jv_k$. Here, $F$ is the sum of forces on a mass (including gravity as a force), $v$ is the mass's velocity, and $T_{ijk}$ is a 3x3x3 "Newtonized" torsion tensor. Similar to Newtonian gravity, our torsion force $F_{t}$ is not a real force but an effect of spacetime being twisted.

$F_{t}$ will not impart angular momentum on a static gyroscope so long as $T$ is constant: points opposite on the disk will have the same $F_{t}$ and the angular momentum contributions cancel. But gyroscopes *will* twist as they move through space (in proportion to their rotation rate and linear velocity). Energy is conserved: $F_{t}*v=0$ since $T$ is antisymmetric. Momentum isn't conserved and we have a preferred reference frame; if torsion is real in whatever is causing the torsion would soak up the missing momentum.

Unlike curvature, which is less relevant for smaller systems, torsion is scale-invariant. Chemistry is different and the Schrödinger equation would be modified. The [Pauli Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation) also has to deal with velocity-dependent forces so presumably there would be some sort of "vector potential".

Would torsion manifest this way "at low energies"?